# How to set dynamic parameter name to type definition

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following code

```
class Person {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public age: number,
  ) { }
}

type BuilderAccesor<T> = {
  [K in keyof T & string as `with${Capitalize<K>}`]: (value: T[K]) => T[K];
};

type PersonBuilder = BuilderAccesor<Person>;
```

What I want to achieve is to change the parameter name to the one that is originally in the class parameter, something like

```
type BuilderAccesor<T> = {
  [K in keyof T & string as `with${Capitalize<K>}`]: ([K]: T[K]) => T[K];
};
```

So that the final type shows

```
type PersonBuilder = {
    withName: (name: string) => string;
    withAge: (age: number) => number;
}
```

Instead of:

```
type PersonBuilder = {
    withName: (value: string) => string;
    withAge: (value: number) => number;
}
```

Is this possible to achieve?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gKGtY6EALogK7BEqIAUue0ADqQEYgCWw0aYAtvAFzRiiNmgDmAGjp4mrDtDBiBXUj2ZIpeAJRZoAX2wHsRAJ4N40AEKk2IACZIAgsGDxUiADwAVAHzQAvFh0ANoA0tCi0ADW8CYoAGbQXtAAZEIkomIKMAAGAO5sRAAWACSYAMJgDIVg7ABe8B6hPno5ALqC1AButaTKXmFtOv5+A6FtANyGU8ZmFgjI6Na2DogBVjb2Ti5uVB4LqGg+U0A)

Comment: You can't convert between string literal types and parameter names, so there's no way to do this programmatically.  You'd have to be willing to add some helper type to manage the mapping between labels and object properties, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlpkxN); which might not be worth your while.  If you want me to write that up as an answer, let me know.  Otherwise I think the answer here is just "no" (which could also be written up, with pointers to docs that say that parameter names and tuple labels are unobservable in the type system).

Comment: Why do you want to change it? It is only for debug purpose. Just curious. I have already seen several similar questions this month